# MYSQL - Not inserting into database?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

My MYSQL query isn't inserting properly via a form I had made. The query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Servers(ip, desc, type, title)
    VALUES($ip, $desc, $type, $title)"
) or die(mysql_error());
```

The MYSQL table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Servers(
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ip varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  desc text NOT NULL,
  type varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  title varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
```

I already have two pre-made rows in the table. The form code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  Title: <input type="text" name="title" /><br />
  IP: <input type="text" name="ip" /><br />
  Description:<br />
  <textarea name="desc"></textarea><br />
  Type: <input type="text" name="type" /><br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit server!" />
</form>
```

When I submit a server, I get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, type,
title) VALUES(a, a, a, a)' at line 1
```

Comment: Btw, you don't need to swap out angle brackets for square ones. Just prefix your html code block with four spaces, and ensure it has a preceding and following carriage return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Servers` (`ip`, `desc`, `type`, `title`) VALUES('".$ip."', '".$desc."', '".$type."', '".$title."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

`desc` is a reserved keyword of MySql, so it cannot be used without backticks.

Comment: Thanks! I used a mix of your answer and Roel's answer and it now works perfectly!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use quotes when inserting string values:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Servers(ip, desc, type, title) VALUES('$ip' , '$desc', '$type', '$title')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

desc is a reserved work and you have to use ``. When your field is a (var)char, not a number,
you have to enclose it in quotes in your script.